# Yii framework: wrong creating urls

Tags: frameworks, yii

I'm learning Yii and got into url creating problem. I have a component urlManager as follows:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
                        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                        'rules'=>array(
                                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                                'admin/useredit/<id:\d+>'=>'admin/useredit',
                        ),
                        'showScriptName'=>false,
                        'urlSuffix'=>'.html',
                ),
```

When I use this:

```
$this->createUrl('admin/useredit',array('id'=>'2'))
```

It's creating 'xxx.com/admin/useredit/.html2' but I expecting 'xxx.com/admin/useredit/2.html'

What may be wrong?

Edit:
The problem is only in CGridView:

```
...
'value' => 'CHtml::link("$data->username","'.$this->createUrl('admin/useredit',array('id'=>$data->id)).'".CHtml::encode($data->id))',
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reorder your rules. The first rule that matches your route will be used. So in your case this is `<controller>/<action>`. You should move your `admin/useredit` rule to the top.

If you want to create an URL in a `CGridView` column you need to surround your expression with `'`. You also don't need to call `createUrl()` because `CHtml::link` will accept a route with parameters.

```
'value'=>'CHtml::link($data->username,array("admin/useredit","id"=>$data->id))'
```