# Is there a precedence urlManager rule?

Tags: php, yii

In my Yii test app, I have 2 types of URL. Example as below:-

```
http://localhost/testapp/index.php?r=post/view&id=1&slug=maximizing-profit
http://localhost/testapp/index.php?r=category/view&slug=investment
```

The first URL have 2 parameter; **`id`** and **`slug`** while second parameter only has **`slug`** parameter

And in my urlManager, I have 2 rules

```
<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>/' => '<controller>/<action>
<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>/' => '<controller>/<action>
```

With this rule, my first URL seems to be malformed whereby it'll be shown as

```
http://localhost/testapp/post/view/maximizing-profit?id=1
```

The second URL on the other hands displayed fine

```
http://localhost/testapp/category/view/investment
```

Is there a rule precedence in urlManager that we should follow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii framework: wrong creating urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669643/yii-framework-wrong-creating-urls). Questions like these pop up every few weeks. Please do some research here on SO first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any rule that matches the URL first will be used.

In your case, simply switch the order of both rules. This is because your slug rules matches numbers as well, including those with only ID. If you switch the rules, those with numbers as IDs will be captured first, followed by those with non-numeric ID.