# Yii Urlmanager rule issue

Tags: php, regex, url, yii

Using Yii framework. I have controller - AvatarController. My rules look like :

```
        'rules' => array(
            'login' => 'user/login',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            'avatar/<hash:\w+>/<size:\d+>' => 'avatar/generate',
        ),
```

And action look like:

```
public function actionGenerate($hash, $size)
{ ...
```

What I want to do is to call this controller/action like

`mydomain.com/avatar/size/48/hash/e4d909c290d0fb1ca068ffaddf22cbd0`

I'm not familiar with regex patterns, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii framework: wrong creating urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669643/yii-framework-wrong-creating-urls)

Answer (score 3):

You need your most specific rules at the top and more general further down. First match wins